# If we run our custom C# commandlets after we run commandlets from an Az module, then our commandlets cannot find Azure assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am developing commandlets in C#. The commandlets use these Azure packages.

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Search.Documents" Version="11.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" Version="1.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" Version="1.37.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" Version="1.37.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.1" />
```

We build the commandlets into an assembly (DLL) and then import that assembly as a module.

```
Import-Module path/to/our/assembly.dll;
```

This usually works terrifically. A problem occurs, though, when we combine our commandlets with those from `Az.Accounts` and/or `Az.Storage`. For instance, the following will throw an error:

```
New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString $StorageAccountConnectionString `
| Get-AzStorageContainer `
| Get-AzStorageBlob;

Invoke-OurCustomCommandlet
```

When we invoke our custom commandlet, we see the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)

How can we resolve this, so that our custom commandlets can interact with the `Az` modules? Our commandlets work fine when we have not run those `Az` module commandlets first.

Comment: You're experiencing dependency conflicts because the AZ cmdlets are using different versions of the same libraries. Here is a recent answer about [resolving dependency conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69403558/9164015). The link to DevBlogs at the bottom might be most useful.