# Issues Instantiating Mimekit.MimeMessage in PowerShell "Could not load file of assembly "System.Buffers" as well as "System.Memory"

Tags: powershell, dependencies, dllimport, mailkit, mimekit

I am working to build a script that utilizes MailKit and MimeKit to send an email using PowerShell. I built a runnable version of this script on my development machine and am now trying to get it working on the server. The first issue I encountered was that I was not being able to use Add-Type like I was on my development machine. When using Add-Type on the server I wish to deploy the script on, I get the following error
[image: Add-Type Error]
(This may be the root of my problem). What I did as a workaround was to use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($PathToDLL)` and it works as expected. To verify it worked, I loaded the MailKit assembly using the above command and was able to instantiate the SMTPClient Object by doing `$SMTP = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient` however if I load the DLL for MimeKit using `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom` and then try to instantiate the object by running `New-Object MimeKit.MimeMessage` I get an error  `Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" arguments": could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory'...`

My next steps were to try installing System.Memory using NuGet, then use `LoadFrom` to import the Assembly into my current session. Once System.Memory is imported, I again try to instantiate Mimekit.MimeMessage and receive the same error but instead of not being able to load System.Memory, it is not able to load System.Buffers. I follow the same procedure to download System.Buffers from Nuget and import it successfully with `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($PathToSystemBuffersDLL)` but I still receive `Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" arguments": could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers version=4.0.2.0., Culture=nuetral etc. The system could not find the file specified.`

I have tried reinstalling the packages with NuGet, tried importing other versions including net462,net461, and any others to no avail. I've done pretty extensive research but I'm a bit stuck as to what to try next. I think something pretty relevant to what I'm experiencing is described in an answer here [Cannot Load Assemblies For .Net Standard library (System.Text.Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436841/cannot-load-assemblies-for-net-standard-library-system-text-json). I used `Install-Package -source 'nuget' $PackageName` to install my packages. It's worth noting that to install these packages I had to use Version 2 of NuGet's API. (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2)

Code that generates error on Windows Server 2016, but not on Windows 10 Pro. Both using PowerShell 5 and .NET Framework 4.8 (4.8.03761 on server and 4.8.04084 on Windows 10)

```
    #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MailKit.3.4.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MailKit.dll" #Gives error
    #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MimeKit.3.4.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MimeKit.dll" #gives error
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MailKit.3.4.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MailKit.dll") #success
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MimeKit.3.4.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MimeKit.dll") #success
    $SMTP = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient #works after loading mailkit assembly
    $Message = New-Object MimeKit.MimeMessage #complains about System.Memory, if I run LoadFrom and add the System.Memory.dll package, will complain about System.Buffers.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who may run into this issue. I have resolved it by switching to PowerShell 7. I can successfully load the DLL with `Add Type -Path $DLLPath`